# R: dplyr::group_by failing on a pxR data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, janitor

`dplyr::group_by()` fails to group the variables of the following data.frame contained in a pc-axis file:

```
library("pacman")
pacman::p_load(pxR, dplyr, janitor)
px_file <- "https://www.pxweb.bfs.admin.ch/DownloadFile.aspx?file=px-x-1502040100_131"
pxR::read.px(base::url(px_file))$DATA$value %>% # the data.frame
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  dplyr::select (student_level = studienstufe, 
                 year = jahr, 
                 counts = value) %>% # dplyr::rename() also fails
  dplyr::group_by (year, student_level) %>% # not grouping!
  dplyr::summarise(totals = sum (counts))
```

I believe it could be due to an encoding issue, but I cannot find the problem. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fault I could find was that you use `select` instead of `rename`. You wrote that `rename` didn't work for you. This worked for me:

```
library("pacman")
library("dplyr")
library("janitor")

# Loading your data
pacman::p_load(pxR, dplyr, janitor)
px_file <- "https://www.pxweb.bfs.admin.ch/DownloadFile.aspx?file=px-x-1502040100_131"
px <- pxR::read.px(base::url(px_file))$DATA$value

# Cleaning the column names
px1 <- px %>% janitor::clean_names()

# Rename the columns
px2 <- px1 %>%
  dplyr::rename (student_level = studienstufe, 
                 sex = geschlecht,
                 year = jahr, 
                 counts = value) 

# Grouping data
px3 <- px2 %>%
  dplyr::group_by (year, student_level) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(totals = sum (counts))
```

I split every step into an own dataframe to see the result. This is not necessary.

If this doesn't work, you may upload your session info.

P.S. I also renamed the column `geschlecht` :)